Permission Denial: android.intent.action.CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS
OS: Android 12
We are getting below crashes in production app, We are using notifee plugin along with react-native-firebase/messaging
Below is the stacktrace
Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: android.intent.action.CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS broadcast from com.test.app (pid=21363, uid=10400) requires android.permission.BROADCAST_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS.
       at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2472)
       at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2456)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2439)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2381)
       at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.closeSystemDialogs(IActivityManager.java:7749)
       at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.sendCloseSystemWindows(PhoneWindow.java:3832)
       at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneFallbackEventHandler.sendCloseSystemWindows(PhoneFallbackEventHandler.java:330)
       at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneFallbackEventHandler.onKeyDown(PhoneFallbackEventHandler.java:157)
       at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneFallbackEventHandler.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneFallbackEventHandler.java:81)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6947)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:6759)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:6228)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:6290)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:6251)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:6425)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:6259)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:6482)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:6232)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:6290)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:6251)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:6259)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:6232)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:6290)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:6251)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:6458)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6620)
       at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:3284)
       at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:2840)
       at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:2831)
       at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:3261)
       at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:154)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:339)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:179)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:344)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8249)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:589)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1071)

"@notifee/react-native": "7.8.0",
"react-native": "0.71.12",
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "19.0.1",

Anyoneknow how to fix this?

add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS" />  to manifest
